# How to determine is an item matches an aphabetic letter in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

What I want to be able to have is to have the following code return true:

```
var reg = new RegExp(/A-Za-z/);
reg === "A";
```

Essentially what I am trying to do is loop through letters and use an if statement that says if item `===` alphabetic letter do something. I hope that makes sense Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/A-Za-z/` matches the characters `A-Za-z` literally (case sensitive)

`/[A-Za-z]/` match a single character present in:

- `A-Z` a single character in the range between A and Z (case
  sensitive)
- `a-z` a single character in the range between a and z (case sensitive)

Try this:

```
var reg = /[A-Za-z]/;

reg.test('A'); // true
reg.test('9'); // false
```

[RegExp.prototype.test()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Comment: +1, but if using a literal, you don't need the constructor (i.e. use either `new RegExp('[A-Za-z]')` or the literal `/[A-Za-z]/` . Also `reg = /[a-z]/i;` should do the job. ;-)